# Which way is better? Save a media file to MongoDB as array of bytes or as string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I'm saving media files (pictures, PDFs, etc.) in MongoDB as array of bytes. I saw examples where people saved it by Encoding and Decoding array of bytes to string. What is the difference? Maybe difference in performance? So which way is better?

I've noticed that when file saved as array of bytes Mongo Management Studio opens collection longer then when it saved like string

Comment: Have you read this [Storing Large Objects and Files in MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb)?

Comment: Liam, yes, i have read this, but there are will be no files with size more then 16MB, because of that i don't want to use GridFS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you want to store the file inside a document.
But have you considered using GridFS vs storing the file inside the document?

Like Liam pointed out, a MongoDB provides a blog-post on GridFS considerations [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb)

One of the advantages in a project I'm working on is that no checking on file-sizes has to be done, and you can simply write and read the file in a binary stream.

From a performance perspective, saving and retrieving the file in binary form is faster than first serializing it to a string.
In a test program, running against a MongoDb 3.2 database, saving a file in binary form in a document was up to 3 times faster than saving the file in a string-serialized form. Which is understandable, since the string-serialized form is simply 'more bytes' to save or read.

In the same test program a quick test was also performed against GridFS, but there you really have to play a round with the chunck-size to get to the best possible performance.

Below a code-dump for a very crude test program *(note that you have to provide the right `example.jpg` yourself and that the database connection has been hard-coded.)*

```
class Program
{
    static bool keepRunning;
    static string fileName = "example.jpg";
    static int numDocs = 571;
    static IMongoDatabase mongoDb;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate
        {
            Exit();
        };

        keepRunning = true;

        SetupMongoDb();

        var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        Console.WriteLine($"Picturesize in bytes: {fileBytes.Length}");

        ClearCollections();

        Console.WriteLine($"Saving {numDocs} pictures to the database.");

        Console.WriteLine("\nStart Saving in Binary Mode.");
        Stopwatch binaryStopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        SaveBinaryBased(numDocs, fileBytes);
        binaryStopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Done Saving in Binary Mode.");

        Console.WriteLine("\nStart Saving in String-based Mode.");
        Stopwatch stringStopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        SaveStringBased(numDocs, fileBytes);
        stringStopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Done Saving in String-based Mode.");

        Console.WriteLine("\nTime Report Saving");
        Console.WriteLine($"   * Total Time Binary for {numDocs} records: {binaryStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
        Console.WriteLine($"   * Total Time String for {numDocs} records: {stringStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");

        Console.WriteLine("\nCollection Statistics:");
        Statistics("binaryPics");
        Statistics("stringBasedPics");

        Console.WriteLine("\nTest Retrieval:");
        Console.WriteLine("\nStart Retrieving from binary collection.");
        binaryStopWatch.Restart();
        RetrieveBinary();
        binaryStopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Done Retrieving from binary collection.");

        Console.WriteLine("\nStart Retrieving from string-based collection.");
        stringStopWatch.Restart();
        RetrieveString();
        stringStopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Done Retrieving from string-based collection.");

        Console.WriteLine("\nTime Report Retrieving:");
        Console.WriteLine($"   * Total Time Binary for retrieving {numDocs} records: {binaryStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
        Console.WriteLine($"   * Total Time String for retrieving {numDocs} records: {stringStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");

        ClearGridFS();
        Console.WriteLine($"\nStart saving {numDocs} files to GridFS:");
        binaryStopWatch.Restart();
        SaveFilesToGridFS(numDocs, fileBytes);
        binaryStopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Saved {numDocs} files to GridFS in {binaryStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");

        Console.WriteLine($"\nStart retrieving {numDocs} files from GridFS:");
        binaryStopWatch.Restart();
        RetrieveFromGridFS();
        binaryStopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved {numDocs} files from GridFS in {binaryStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");

        while (keepRunning)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    private static void Exit()
    {
        keepRunning = false;
    }

    private static void ClearCollections()
    {
        var collectionBin = mongoDb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("binaryPics");
        var collectionString = mongoDb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("stringBasedPics");

        collectionBin.DeleteMany(new BsonDocument());
        collectionString.DeleteMany(new BsonDocument());
    }

    private static void SetupMongoDb()
    {
        string hostName = "localhost";
        int portNumber = 27017;
        string databaseName = "exampleSerialization";

        var clientSettings = new MongoClientSettings()
        {
            Server = new MongoServerAddress(hostName, portNumber),
            MinConnectionPoolSize = 1,
            MaxConnectionPoolSize = 1500,
            ConnectTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30),
            SocketTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 30),
            WaitQueueTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)
        };

        mongoDb = new MongoClient(clientSettings).GetDatabase(databaseName);
    }

    private static void SaveBinaryBased(int numDocuments, byte[] content)
    {
        var collection = mongoDb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("binaryPics");

        BsonDocument baseDoc = new BsonDocument();
        baseDoc.SetElement(new BsonElement("jpgContent", content));

        for (int i = 0; i < numDocs; ++i)
        {
            baseDoc.SetElement(new BsonElement("_id", Guid.NewGuid()));
            baseDoc.SetElement(new BsonElement("filename", fileName));
            baseDoc.SetElement(new BsonElement("title", $"picture number {i}"));
            collection.InsertOne(baseDoc);
        }
    }

    private static void SaveStringBased(int numDocuments, byte[] content)
    {
        var collection = mongoDb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("stringBasedPics");

        BsonDocument baseDoc = new BsonDocument();
        baseDoc.SetElement(new BsonElement("jpgStringContent", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content)));

        for (int i = 0; i < numDocs; ++i)
        {
            baseDoc.SetElement(new BsonElement("_id", Guid.NewGuid()));
            baseDoc.SetElement(new BsonElement("filename", fileName));
            baseDoc.SetElement(new BsonElement("title", $"picture number {i}"));
            collection.InsertOne(baseDoc);
        }
    }

    private static void Statistics(string collectionName)
    {
        new BsonDocument { { "collstats", collectionName } };
        var command = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument { { "collstats", collectionName } });
        var stats = mongoDb.RunCommand(command);

        Console.WriteLine($"  * Collection      : {collectionName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  * Count           : {stats["count"].AsInt32} documents");
        Console.WriteLine($"  * Average Doc Size: {stats["avgObjSize"].AsInt32} bytes");
        Console.WriteLine($"  * Total Storage   : {stats["storageSize"].AsInt32} bytes");
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }

    private static void RetrieveBinary()
    {
        var collection = mongoDb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("binaryPics");
        var docs = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToEnumerable();

        foreach (var doc in docs)
        {
            byte[] fileArray = doc.GetElement("jpgContent").Value.AsByteArray;
            // we can simulate that we do something with the results but that's not the purpose of this experiment
            fileArray = null;
        }
    }

    private static void RetrieveString()
    {
        var collection = mongoDb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("stringBasedPics");
        var docs = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToEnumerable();

        foreach (var doc in docs)
        {
            // Simply get the string, we don't want to hit the performance test
            // with a conversion to a byte array
            string result = doc.GetElement("jpgStringContent").Value.AsString;
        }
    }

    private static void SaveFilesToGridFS(int numFiles, byte[] content)
    {
        var bucket = new GridFSBucket(mongoDb, new GridFSBucketOptions
        {
            BucketName = "pictures"
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; ++i)
        {
            string targetFileName = $"{fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - ".jpg".Length)}{i}.jpg";
            int chunkSize = content.Length <= 1048576 ? 51200 : 1048576;
            bucket.UploadFromBytes(targetFileName, content, new GridFSUploadOptions { ChunkSizeBytes = chunkSize });
        }
    }

    private static void ClearGridFS()
    {
        var bucket = new GridFSBucket(mongoDb, new GridFSBucketOptions { BucketName = "pictures" });
        bucket.Drop();
    }

    private static void RetrieveFromGridFS()
    {
        var bucket = new GridFSBucket(mongoDb, new GridFSBucketOptions { BucketName = "pictures" });
        var filesIds = mongoDb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("pictures.files").Find(new BsonDocument()).ToEnumerable().Select(doc => doc.GetElement("_id").Value);

        foreach (var id in filesIds)
        {
            var fileBytes = bucket.DownloadAsBytes(id);
            fileBytes = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question

Comment: Yes, I want to store my files inside a document, size of file will be less then 3MB, and I don't think that document will be more then 16MB. In the document I have field with size of file and validation on it. I don't have problems with checking file-size