# Whats the best way to save files on backend with mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm in the middle of writing a mean stack application and I'm a beginner programmer.

The user must be able to submit some strings from form fields together with a file which would be an image or a pdf.

I´ve looked at Multer then I could store the path to the file together with the form data in MongoDB.

I also found something on GridFS.

What would be the best and easiest way to make this work?

Comment: I've tried Multer and I think it is exactly what you need. It's easy to use, has good documentation and a lot of "how to upload file on sever" tutorials

Answer (score 1):

As usual: it depends....

In one of the projects I am working on, we have deliberately chosen to use the database to store the files. One of the reasons is to prevent yet another security and configuration artefact to the solution by introducing a file-management requirements.

Now, mind you that storing a file on disk is just faster than storing it in your database. But if performance is not a really big issue, storing it in MongoDB is a perfectly valid option as well (after all, it is a NoSQL solution that uses binary serialization as one of its core components).
 You can choose to store files either in one of the normal collections, or in GridFS.

As a rule of thumb: if the files in your solution do not exceed the 16MB, then you can save them as (part of) a document in a normal collection. If they are larger than 16 MB, it is best to save them in GridFS.
 When saving in GridFS though, you have to play around with chunck-sizes to find an optimal performance.

A blog post on GridFS can be found [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb)

In the past I have posted something in another answer on binary- vs. string-based serialization and the use of GridFS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41375192/which-way-is-better-save-a-media-file-to-mongodb-as-array-of-bytes-or-as-string/41442109#41442109) 
 Note: that post is in C#, but that should not really pose a problem.

Hope this helps, and good luck honing your programmer skills. The best way to learn is to ask and experiment (a lot).

Answer (score -1):

You would never want to save the file as binary data on the DB for the obvious reasons so If you want to store files on the local storage where your app runs then multer is the package that you need.

```
var path = require('path')
var multer = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        console.log(file)
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

app.post('/api/file', function(req, res) {
    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage
    }).single('userFile')
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        res.end('File is uploaded')
    })
})
```

You can change a code bit as per your requirements and naming conventions you want. I would suggest that you keep the predictable filename so you won't even need to store the path in DB i.e. for userid 5 file will be stored at /img/user/profile/5.jpg or something similar.

And you can also try storing files on the cloud storage like aws s3 or google storage if you are having too much of files.